# std_logic or std_ulogic?

Tags: vhdl

It seems that the world has decided that `std_logic` (and `std_logic_vector`) are the default way of representing bits in VHDL. The alternative would be `std_ulogic`, which is not resolved.

This surprises me because usually, you're *not* describing a *bus*, so you don't want multiple drivers and you don't need to *resolve* a signal. The advantage of `std_ulogic` would be that the compiler warns you early on if you have multiple drivers.

Question: is this just a cultural / historical thing, or are there still technical reasons to use std_logic?

Comment: The "world" is wrong. Smart engineers use std_ulogic as because it has the correct semantics.

Comment: @wjl I'll interpret that as "it's a cultural/historical thing".
Your answer below is much more helpful than the comment up here.

Comment: I wrote the comment first, then thought it would be more appropriate to leave an answer with more specifics. Sorry, I guess it does sound a little flippant. But my comment is literal in that most people start out using std_logic because they learned it that way, then after a while they start to wonder about std_ulogic, they look up it, realize it's semantics, and then convert to it. =)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Std_logic is a subtype of std_ulogic and has *exactly* one extra property: it's resolved if there are multiple drivers.

Regardless of common practice, std_ulogic is the correct type to use for non-resolved signals that need 9-valued logic. (Often, using "bit" is even more correct -- for instance, on some FPGA architectures that do not have any such thing as an 'X' or a 'U').

Basically, the best thing to do is use the correct type for the job. Often bad practices get propagated by people just parroting the style that they see others use, do without understanding why.

Comment: The architecture may not have a 'U', but it's often useful to simulate as if it did as you can find incorrect initialisations.  +1 for "the best thing to do is use the correct type for the job", but we tend to learn as we go along about what's "best" :)

Comment: Also, the metavalues become "don't care" in synthesis, which allows for more optimizations.

Answer (score 9):

My history is this:

I started off (in about 1999 IIRC) using `std_ulogic*` all the time - as it's the right thing to do, for just the reasons you describe.

Then I had to interface to a bunch of wizard generated vendor IP which all had `std_logic`s all over the interface.  Which meant conversions on the port-mappings (for the `_vector` elements), and I got lazy and moved over to using `std_logic*`.

However, I seem to make very few "double-driver" mistakes, so I haven't missed `std_ulogic` as much as I would've thought.  And Modelsim's `drivers` command makes it very easy to find "who is driving what" when I do occasionally need to...

Comment: Yeah, IP cores (and especially stuff that is automatically translated from Verilog) tends to use std_logic. 

Your answer seems to suggest that the reason is mostly "cultural/historical".

Comment: You never have to convert between std_logic and std_ulogic on ports. Did you mean you had to convert between std_logic_vector and std_ulogic_vector?

Comment: @wjl: sorry, yes that's what I meant.  I'll update the post.

Comment: AFAIK, the std_logic and std_ulogic are assignment-compatible since they have the same base type. So, there should be no need for manual conversion.

Comment: @Val: that's what wjl said (and I agree with) - but the `*vector` port parts still need conversions

Comment: I read the specification and wonder why. The arrays must be compatible if elements are. Modelsim says that all you need is vhdl2008 compatibility!

Comment: Just to make sure that I understood the trouble that motivated you to transition from using `std_ulogic_vector` to `std_logic_vector`, if it were possible for you to use VHDL-2008 at that time, the problem wouldn't have existed, is that right?

Comment: @rick - yes it was very pre-2008 when I made the shift.

Answer (score 4):

IIRC the famed Reuse Methodology Manual recommended `std_logic(_vector)`, so maybe methodology groups in companies etc. spread that further in the form of (mandatory) coding guides.
Personally, +1 for using `std_ulogic` when possible.

Answer (score 2):

I know its a horribly colored ppt slideshow, but it explains the difference pretty good:

http://web.archive.org/web/20151026150828/http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~jmor159/reconfig/ppt/ResolutionFunctions.ppt

Comment: broken link, archived here: http://web.archive.org/web/20151026150828/http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~jmor159/reconfig/ppt/ResolutionFunctions.ppt